# Issue with Conway's Game of Life in Python

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

I've been trying to create the Game of Life in python but I've been struggling to get the correct result no matter how I write the rules, so I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong.

I've tried writing my rules for iterating over the cells various times, writing the base code to use multiple lists or using lists of classes, but every time the result comes off wrong and after 5 or so iterations the simulation just kinda plateaus.

Here is my sourcecode:

````
import os
import random
import time
 
class Cell():
    def __init__(self, ID, state, previous_state, neighbours, index):
        self.ID = ID
        self.state = state
        self.previous_state = previous_state
        self.neighbours = neighbours
        self.index = index
 
    def Get_Neighbours(self,grid):
        neighbours = 0
        index_y = self.index[0]
        index_x = self.index[1]
 
        if index_x < height - 1:
            if grid[index_x + 1][index_y].state == 1:
                neighbours += 1
        if index_x > 0:
            if grid[index_x - 1][index_y].state == 1:
                neighbours += 1
        if index_y < width - 1:
            if grid[index_x][index_y + 1].state == 1:
                neighbours += 1
        if index_y > 0:
            if grid[index_x][index_y - 1].state == 1:
                neighbours += 1
        return neighbours
 
def Draw_grid(grid):
    os.system("cls") 
    for Cells in Cell_grid:
        print_row = []
        for Cell in Cells:
            if Cell.state == 1:
                print_row.append("#")
            else:
                print_row.append(" ")
        print(" ".join(print_row))
    print(Cell_grid[1][1].neighbours)
    time.sleep(.5)
 
def Iterate_Cells(Cell_grid):
    for Cells in Cell_grid:
        for Cell in Cells:
            Cell.neighbours = Cell.Get_Neighbours(Cell_grid)
            if Cell.state == 1 & Cell.neighbours <= 1:
                Cell.state = 0
            elif Cell.state == 1 & Cell.neighbours in [2,3]:
                Cell.state = 1
            elif Cell.state == 1 & Cell.neighbours == 4:
                Cell.state = 0
            elif Cell.state == 0 & Cell.neighbours == 3:
                Cell.state = 1
 
"""
A cell dies if it has less than two living neighbors.
A cell survives until the next generation if it has two or three neighbors.
A cell with more than three neighbors dies.
A dead cell with exactly three neighbors turns into a living cell.
"""
 
width = 30
height = 30
interation = 0
 
Cell_grid = [[Cell(0,0,0,0,0) for i in range(width)] for j in range(height)]
counter = 0
 
""" initialize cells """
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
 
        alive_seed = random.random()
        if alive_seed > .2:
            Cell_grid[i][j].state = 1
        else:
            Cell_grid[i][j].state = 0
 
        Cell_grid[i][j].index = (i,j)
 
        Cell_grid[i][j].ID = counter
        counter += 1
 
while True:
    Draw_grid(Cell_grid)
    Iterate_Cells(Cell_grid)
    ```
````

Comment: You have to build a new Grid with each iteration, as opposed to updating the current one (since your new and old states get mixed up).

Answer (score 0):

One problem is here and in similar checks:

```
if Cell.state == 1 & Cell.neighbours <= 1
```

`&` is the *bitwise* AND operator, not *logical* AND.  Looking at the [operator precedence rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), this will be parsed as:

```
if Cell.state == (1 & Cell.neighbours) <= 1
```

which, thanks to [comparison chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), is expanded as:

```
if Cell.state == (1 & Cell.neighbours) and (1 & Cell.neighbours) <= 1
```

Instead, you need to use the `and` keyword:

```
if Cell.state == 1 and Cell.neighbours <= 1
```